# Getting average of square inside a 2D array

Tags: java, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array, average

I have a 2D array like this:

[image]

The user then enters an odd value (length) as well as co-ordinates for an average calculation for example:

[image]

Where the length value is halved and added/subtracted from the co-ordinates to form a square to calculate the average of that square of values

This is my loop, but it doesn't calculate the average correctly

```java
int counter = 0;
double sum = 0;
for (int x = x1; x < x2; x++) {
    for (int y = y1; y < y2; y++) {
        sum = sum + (array[x][y]);
        counter++;
    }
}
average = sum / counter;
```

Sorry for the bad diagrams

When I run the loop with this array and the values provided the output I get is 3.5 when it is meant to be 3.2

Comment: What does "it doesn't calculate the average correctly" mean? Could you provide examples? In your diagram the values seem to have a sum of 80 so the average would be 80/25 = 3,2.

Comment: Your approach seems correct btw, the only problem I can see is that you should use `x <= x2´ and `y <= y2` since it looks like `x2` and `y2` are inclusive coordinates. Your code currently skips the last column and last row of the rectangle.

Comment: Thanks, I figured out my error, it was me being silly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem related with your bounds. Don't forget if exceed  the length of dimensions,  this will throw IndexOutOfBoundsException.

```java
// x < x2 must to be x <= x2
for (int x = x1; x <= x2; x++) {
    // y < y2 must to be y <= x2
    for (int y = y1; y <= y2; y++) {
        sum = sum + (array[x][y]);
        counter++;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are right, I just added <= and now I get IndexOutOfBoundsException,

Comment: If I hard code the co-ordinates in x1 = 1 and x2 = 5, y1 = 3, y2 = 7 I still get the exception

Comment: Alright I figured it out, I am pretty silly for swapping the y and the x-axis, sorry for the trouble

Comment: I thought you were swapping :)